# How to create Dynamic Table View cells With multiple View Controller in swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Hi all.** I'm troubling with tableView in swift. Actually i created the table view with **two rows**(About and Login) in main view controller. Problem at initial, when i click the about or Login , then the New View controller **is not opened.** But, I try second time to another one row, then the **first clicked view Controller is opened at this time of Clicking.** so, this cycles shown wrong view controller at every time of clicking. Please tell me as whats wrong with my Code?? Please refer **screenshot** given below.Thanks in advance!!!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var titles = ["About","LogIn"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titles.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableCell
        cell.label.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        switch indexPath.row
        {
        case 0: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aboutSegue", sender: self)
        case 1: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
        default: break
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "aboutSegue"
        {
          let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! about
            vc.title = "About"
        }
        else
        {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! login
            vc.title = "Login"

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }


}
```

**Below Screen shown, I clicked About Row. But, the Login ViewController is Opened.**

[image]

**This is my Story Board Connections.**
[image]

Comment: instead of a dynamic cells you should use static cell (where you would only need to use two rows)

Comment: @Lamar, Actually this was a demo. I must use dynamic cells on my project. But **no one view controller not open on first click.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row
    {
    case 0: 
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aboutSegue", sender: self) 
        break;
    case 1: 
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: self)
        break;

    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks G. I update it. but, same problem came. Any View Controller _Does not Open_ in **FIRST CLICK** of table view Rows.

Comment: Actually i used this , `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {print("Cell Clicked")}` the print war printed on time of after the second click with dirrerent row.

Comment: Hahahaha!!! Actually i not been used didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. That is the problem with first time click. I Just replace didDeselectRowAtIndexPath to didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. thanks Man